# Django - What happens when setting WEB_CONCURRENCY too high in heroku 1xdyno

Tags: django, heroku, concurrency, gunicorn

I have a `Django` app running in `Heroku` with `GUnicorn`, I have `1Xdyno` and just found that you can set your `WEB_CONCURRENCY`.

What's the optimal `WEB_CONCURRENCY`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Article [Deploying Python Applications with Gunicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn) tells about various parameters of Gunicorn and their effect on Heroku.

Below is the text copied from this article regarding `WEB_CONCURRENCY`

`Gunicorn forks multiple system processes within each dyno to allow a Python app to support multiple concurrent requests without requiring them to be thread-safe. In Gunicorn terminology, these are referred to as worker processes (not to be confused with Heroku worker processes, which run in their own dynos).`

`Each forked system process consumes additional memory. This limits how many processes you can run in a single dyno. With a typical Django application memory footprint, you can expect to run 2–4 Gunicorn worker processes on a 1X dyno. Your application may allow for a variation of this, depending on your application’s specific memory requirements.`

`We recommend setting a configuration variable for this setting, so you can tweak it without editing code and redeploying your application.`

```
$ heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=3
```